# Convertir string a int 32 y almacenar su resultado

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy desarrollando un juego multijugador en Unity usando los servicios de Google Play Game Services (GPGS), cada uno de los jugadores que se conecta obtiene un id de jugador por medio de GPGS es id es un string el cual necesito convertir a entero y sus elementos sumarlos para obtener un valor numérico de cada usuario y poder realizar alguna acción determinada.

El problema no es convertir el string a int, es ya convertido no puedo realizar ningún tipo de operación con ellos.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
//Declaración de variables
char[] caracter;
int[] valId;

//Inicialización de variables
caracter = nextParticipantId.ToCharArray();
valId = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

//Sección del código
foreach( char letter in caracter) {
    Debug.Log("La letra es: " + letter);
    Debug.Log("El valor de la letra es: " + Convert.ToInt32(letter));
    valId[i] += Convert.ToInt32(letter);
}
```

El primer Debug me muestra la letra sin problema, el segundo me muestra su valor sin ningun problema también, el conflicto es cuando trato de sumar los valores de esas letras.

Comment: Hola, Gracias a todos ya lo pude solucionar, era un problema al incializar la variable, y para comentar, si era necesario tomar el valor ASCII del carácter, ya que era una string que podia contener letras, numeros, simbolos, etc. Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 2):

Debes usar `Convert.ToInt32`o `Int32.Parse` pero ten encuentra que debes almacenar el resultado en otra variable de tipo entero para poder manipularlo.

Ejemplo:

```
var cadena = "1234";
var numero = Convert.ToInt32(cadena);
numero += 1; // ahora es 1235
```

Ten en cuenta que cadena sigue siendo una cadena.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Bien, nunca he usado la clase `Convert` pero haciendo pruebas con sus funciones de conversión, me he encontrado con que talvez tu problema sea el siguiente:

```
char Caracter = '3'; // 51 En ASCII ...
int Valor = Convert.ToInt32(Caracter); // Valor actual: 51
```

Por lo que cuando intentas convertir un caracter usando `Convert` estas tomando su valor en la tabla de caracteres ASCII y no el número real, te recomiendo hacer cualquiera de las siguientes acciones:

Tomando como ejemplo el siguiente caracter:

```
char c = '3'; // 51
```

Cambiar la función por `int.Parse(string)`:

```
int V = int.Parse(c.ToString());
```

O realizar un cast a string directamente en la función `Convert.ToInt32(object)`:

```
int V = Convert.ToInt32(c.ToString());
```

Si lo que quieres es sacar el valor actual del caracter y no el valor en la tabla ASCII.

---

### Edit:

Aplicando la solución a tu problema actual, solo debes cambiar esta linea:

```
valId[i] += Convert.ToInt32(letter);
```

Por:

```
valId[i] += Convert.ToInt32(letter.ToString());
```

Y, mirando un poco mas tu código, de donde sale el indice del array? Según veo, usas el bucle `foreach`, ¿Seguro que no asignas todos los valores al mismo indice?

Espero te haya ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que no modificas el índice del array que estás utilizando:

```
//Declaración de variables
char[] caracter;
int[] valId;

//Inicialización de variables
caracter = nextParticipantId.ToCharArray();
valId = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

//Sección del código
int i = 0;
foreach( char letter in caracter) {
    Debug.Log("La letra es: " + letter);
    int letra = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
    Debug.Log("El valor de la letra es: " + letra);
    valId[i++] += letra;
}
```